# Nested Spring TxProxyTemplate issue

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, weblogic, spring-transactions

I have the following config.

```
<bean id="abcManager" parent="TxProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.x.y.AbcManagerImpl">
          <property name="abcDAO" ref="abcDAO"/>
          <property name="xyzManager" ref="xyzManager"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="xyzManager" parent="TxProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.x.y.XyzManagerImpl">
          <property name="abcDAO" ref="abcDAO"/>
          <property name="anotherManager" ref="anotherManager"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="anotherManager" parent="TxProxyTemplate">
    <property name="target">
      <bean class="com.x.y.AnotherManagerImpl">
        <property name="abcDAO" ref="abcDAO"/>
        <property name="oneMoreManager" ref="oneMoreManager"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What is the issue with the following configuration? will having the same DAO at the different levels cause concurency issues?

We found that we get lots of weblogic connection releases when we have high load.

How is this related to the connection release issue?

We use Hibernate for DAO operations.

Comment: Can you state which problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: weblogic closing DB connections before transaction completes. ( not a timeout ), but mostly same connection is opened and closed from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, analyse the logs to see when spring creates and closes transactions.
Set the logger for org.springframework.transaction to DEBUG for this.

Next my guess is you need to examine your @Transactional annotations (which I assume you use on your managers (=services?). Make sure the propagation is set correctly because this might be related to your issue (hard to say without seeing your manager's code of course).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:

> What is the issue with the following configuration? will having the same DAO at the different levels cause concurency issues?

Nothing, and no.  I don't see anything wrong with this.  Not sure what you mean about 'same DAO' - you don't have the same DAO.  You have the same parent, but 3 distinct DAOs.

If you're asking, then, why is weblogic closing your DB connections before your transaction completes, we wouldn't be able to answer that with the information above.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing his config but assuming he used the default scope to create the abcDAO bean this will be a singleton so it is the same DAO that is used. However, this should not be related at all to his issue.